# NDKBuild Failure in android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm having trouble getting my NDK to compile properly in Android Studio. Whenever I try running to compile I am getting the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'. A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''
```

### build.gradle:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.android.apps.watchme"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        sourceSets.main{
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        }
        project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3, 'mips':5, 'mips64':6, 'x86':8, 'x86_64':9] //versionCode digit for each supported ABI, with 64bit>32bit and x86>armeabi-*
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            // assign different version code for each output
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
        // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
        task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine 'C:\\Users\\RAM-RAMADEVI\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
            } else {
                commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
            }
        }
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev120-1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

### local.properties:-

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\RAM-RAMADEVI\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\RAM-RAMADEVI\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sd
```

k

Comment: did u use --info  and or --debug  to get details from gradle ?

Comment: No when i run my app i am getting this error

Comment: how can i solve this can you please help me please

Comment: ./gradlew --info --debug :app:ndkBuild     on the commandline might provide details

Comment: Hi how can debug app:ndkBuild on the commandline ?